# Not able to write to stdin in Windows subprocess

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, ansys

I am trying to interact with a Windows command-line program using Python. I am using the `subprocess` module for this. Below is the code that starts up the program.

```
kwargs = dict(stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
              stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
              stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
              universal_newlines=True)
p = subprocess.Popen("ansys191.exe", **kwargs)
```

This opens the program with a new console window. I am able to read from its `stdout` using the following code.

```
while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline().strip()
    if line: print(line)
    if line.startswith("BEGIN:") or line.startswith("PREP7:"):
        break
```

After starting up, the program stops with a `BEGIN:` prompt. It does not exit. However, it doesn't work when I try to write a command to its `stdin`, such as the following.

```
p.stdin.write("/prep7")
p.stdout.readline() #Blocks here
```

Here's a screenshot of the code and the window. There are no other windows opened by the command.

[image: Console window screenshot]

After reading the "/prep7" command, the program is supposed to write some text to `stdout` and stop with a `PREP7:` prompt. However, if I type something into the new console window, I am able to read more data from its `stdout`.

Am I missing something here? Will I have to use `win32gui` to find the handle to the window and write to it?

Comment: I can see that you have not ended you command (`p.stdin.write("/prep7")`) with a newline. Few programs are designed not to read full files. What happens with `p.stdin.write("/prep7\n")`

Comment: I tried that as well. Still the same outcome.

Comment: It's interesting that you see console-like window with `shell=True`. You don't need the `shell` argument, and generally shouldn't use it. But since you're using it, I would expect a new console window to be hidden if it's the regular console that's hosted by conhost.exe. Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: @eryksun I initially tried without the `shell=True` argument. I don't think it made a difference in the behavior. For clarity, I have removed it from the original question now. I've also added a screenshot of the code and the window it opened. I am running the code using a jupyter notebook. I have tried it through a regular python file also. The behavior is the same.

Comment: If it has the console properties dialog in the control menu, then probably the process allocates a new console (or maybe creates a console subprocess) for output. Apparently it's reading directly from the console (e.g. by opening "CONIN$"). You can attach to and write input to this console, but it's not simple. Free the current console via `FreeConsole` (first spawn a child process that waits for a signal, in case you need to reattach to the current console), attach to the target console via `AttachConsole`, and use `WriteConsoleInput`. These functions can be called with PyWin32 or ctypes.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks, but I am not too familiar with windows programming using python. I tried to find some info on what you have advised, but couldn't achieve much. Can you share some code as an example?